# alignof not declared in this scope?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ (know some python but not fluent) and am learning from reference documentations.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdalign.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    alignof; //error:'alignof' not declared in this scope
}
```

I added stalign header, but I am still getting the same error. I also tried std::algnment_of, but still the same problem.

I am using the Dev-C++ compiler.

Edit: I am only experimenting, while learning about data structure alignment.

Comment: What do you expect `alignof;` to do? The `alignof` macro in [`<stdalign.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types) is a C11 feature, which is not a part of c++. In c++, [`alignof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignof) is an operator, a built-in feature of the language that doesn't require an include.

Comment: Dev-C++ is an IDE, not a compiler to be exact.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux [`alignof` is part of C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/alignof). Nonetheless, of course, the OP’s usage is wrong.

Comment: `"using namespaces"` is not spelled correctly. Neither is `<stalign.h>`. Please paste the code you actually passed to the compiler.

Comment: @idmean Doesn't seem to be a shipped with the Visual C++ 2013.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense because you have no framework to ask from. Don't try to learn from reference documentation. Get [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?lq=1). I'd recommend _Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++_  by Bjarne Stroustrup

Comment: You may need to configure your compiler to use C++11 or C++14 mode. And learn to use `alignof` correctly - you can't just write it by itself without an operand.

Comment: @Ron [Apparently true.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) It’s part of the standard nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

You're not not using `alignof` in the right way.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std:: cout<< sizeof(int) << ' ' << alignof(int) << '\n'; //This is how to use it.
    return 0;
}
```

Typical output:

```
4 4
```

Size and alignment varies from platform to platform but `sizeof(int)==alignof(int)` known as being 'fully aligned' is commonly required (or just best performance) on modern platforms.

Edit: It's been pointed out you don't need to `#include <cstdalign>` to use `alignof` but the other point remains. `#include <stdalign.h>` is not the recommended way to import C standard libraries and you should use the c-prefix model `#include <cstdalign>` where you do.

Comment: You don't need to include `cstdalign` (or anything else) for `alignof` in C++.

Comment: @interjay. My mistak and bad habit.